# error: expected initializer before '<' token | global

Tags: c++

I have a class with a template like this:

```
template <template <class, class> class ContainerType>
```

And I set some global functions and static in the private field ..

I achieved my these functions outside the class and before any function I declare the template

```
template <template <class, class> class ContainerType>
```

But with such a function for all I get this error:

> error: expected initializer before '<' token

```
    template<template<class, class> class ContainerType>
    void Book<ContainerType>::listCopier(const List_to_copy<ContainerType>& that)
    {
        if(mylist.begin() != mylist.end())
            std::for_each(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), DeleteLIST());
        _this = this;
        std::for_each(that.mylist.begin(), that.mylist.end(), myAllocator);
    }
```

What it can be and how I solve it!?

Comment: Read the chapter about templates would be a good start

Comment: Does it NEED to be nested like that?

Comment: I read it !
But I do not know what causes this problem ...

Comment: @מג'דשרקייה please post a minimal code snippet that we can attempt to compile and reproduces the issue. What you have above is non-valid. It does not declare or define a class/function. Your snippet is part of a declaration. Look [here](http://ideone.com/haQDHf) for an example that works.

Comment: @polarysekt : What do you mean !?

Comment: I mean, you can't use `template <class ContainerType>`?

Comment: I used it to mold itself to be the container and its contents

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 template<template<class, class> class ContainerType>
 void Book::listCopier(const List_to_copy<ContainerType>& that)
 { ... }
```